Gitlab CI/CD, Kubernetes runner, docker build - composer SSL connection timeout
I have a Gitlab CI/CD pipeline, that previously I ran on a Docker runner located on prem. I've now installed a Gitlab runner on my Kubernetes cluster, but one of my pipeline jobs no longer works - specifically, the build of a PHP docker container fails because Composer cannot download packages. I'm at a loss to understand why.
Dockerfile:
FROM php:8.2-fpm-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add git \
        zip \
        libzip-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        mysql-client \
        runc \
        imagemagick \
        imagemagick-dev \
        php82-bcmath \
        php82-calendar \
        php82-exif \
        php82-gd \
        php82-pdo_mysql \
        php82-pdo_pgsql \
        php82-pcntl \
        php82-zip

ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod uga+x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync && \
    install-php-extensions mcrypt \
    pcntl \
    redis \
    zip
        
COPY . /var/www

WORKDIR /var/www

RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" \
    && php composer-setup.php \
    && php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" 

RUN php composer.phar config allow-plugins.composer/installers true \
    && php composer.phar install --no-dev --no-scripts \
    && rm composer.phar

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data \
        /var/www/storage \
        /var/www/bootstrap/cache

Gitlab K8S runner config:
gitlabUrl: https://gitlab.com
rbac: {create: true}
runnerToken: supersecrettoken
privileged: true
namespace: gitlab
runners:
  config: |
      [[runners]]
        name = "k3s-runner"
        url = "{{ .Values.gitlabUrl }}"
        executor = "kubernetes"
        [runners.kubernetes]
          namespace = "{{.Values.namespace}}"
          image = "docker:24.0.5"
          privileged = true
          cpu_limit = "2"
          memory_limit = "8Gi"

Gitlab CI/CD job:
docker_build_app:
  image: docker:24.0.5
  stage: docker_build
  dependencies:
    - composer
    - npm
  services:
    - name: docker:24.0.5-dind
      alias: docker
      command: ["--tls=false"]
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
    HEALTHCHECK_TCP_PORT: 2375
  script:
    - echo -n $CI_JOB_TOKEN | docker login -u gitlab-ci-token --password-stdin $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY/myproject/myapp/app:latest || true
    - docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml up -d --build app
    - docker tag $CI_REGISTRY/myproject/myapp/app $CI_REGISTRY/myproject/myapp/app:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY/myproject/myapp/app:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
    - docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml rm app
  environment:
    name: staging

Everything works until the "composer.phar install" command in the Dockerfile, then composer fails with the following errors:
#13 0.415    0/146 [>---------------------------]   0%    Failed to download php-http/discovery from dist: curl error 28 while downloading https://api.github.com/repos/php-http/discovery/zipball/61e1a1eb69c92741f5896d9e05fb8e9d7e8bb0cb: SSL connection timeout

Repeated 146 times for each of the composer packages I require. If I pause my K8S runner and switch back to my old docker one, it works fine.
I'm at a loss to explain what is happening here. I think it might be something related to K8S networking maybe, but I have no restrictive NetworkPolicy or anything and prior steps including downloading composer itself work fine. It's just pulling the packages that fails.
Anyone have a clue what I should try next?

you either have no connectivity or the network is slow. see as well composer times out no matter what I do #11036.
